# MYSQL rownumber insert into a table

Tags: mysql, numbers, row

I want to find the row number for a grouping and insert into a table for further querying .
this is the code I came up with but it doesnt work . I mean the insert doesnt work the query alone does . Please suggest a work around .I tried to put this code in a stored procedure but that does'nt work too.The error returned is Subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
set @type ='';
set @row_number =1;

insert into newtable(type,actualdeparturetime,actualarrivaltime,dummy_1,dummy_2,row_number)
select type, actualdeparturetime,actualarrivaltime,
@row_number:=if(@type=type,@row_number+1,1) as dummy_1,
@type := type as dummy_2,
@row_number as row_number
FROM sourcetable f
where actualarrivaltime<> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
AND actualarrivaltime > (now()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
order by type ;
```

Comment: The SELECT is a subquery and should be in "(" ")".

Comment: sorry I don't understand can you please rewrite the code and show me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query, rewritten so the variable initialization is in the `from` clause:

```
insert into newtable(type, actualdeparturetime, actualarrivaltime,
                     dummy_1, dummy_2, row_number
                    )
    select type, actualdeparturetime, actualarrivaltime,
           @row_number := if(@type=type, @row_number+1, 1) as dummy_1,
           @type := type as dummy_2,
           @row_number as row_number
    from sourcetable f cross join
         (select @type := '',  @row_number := 1) vars
    where actualarrivaltime <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND
          actualarrivaltime > (now()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    order by type ;
```

I don't see any subqueries, so I don't see how that particular error could be occurring.

If `dummy_1` and `dummy_2` are not needed, you could write this as:

```
insert into newtable(type, actualdeparturetime, actualarrivaltime, row_number
                    )
    select type, actualdeparturetime, actualarrivaltime,
           @row_number := if(@type = type, @row_number+1, if(@type := type is null, 1, 1)) as row_number,
    from sourcetable f cross join
         (select @type := '',  @row_number := 1) vars
    where actualarrivaltime <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND
          actualarrivaltime > (now()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    order by type ;
```

This moves the assignment of `@type` to the `else` clause of the `if`.  This version is also safer, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of processing of `select` expressions.  If they were processed in reverse order, the variables would be all messed up in the original version.